# Determining \$I_{peak}\$ and \$f_{min}\$ and \$f_{max}\$ for MP4569 buck IC

Tags: buck, step-down

Trying to figure out what inductance value is needed for my application of [MP4569](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP4569/document_id/963).
They give the minimum inductance value in terms of \$I_{peak}\$ (page 12):

\$L_{MIN}={{V_{IN(MAX)}{\times}t_{ON(MIN)}}\over{I_{peak}}}\$

and the datasheet says "*the Ipeak is fixed, for given input voltage and output voltage*"

I understand that \$I_{OUT}\$ cannot be more than half \$I_{peak}\$ with this converter because it always waits for the \$I_{L}\$ to drop to zero before each new cycle, but I don't understand how to determine this fixed \$I_{peak}\$ value based on \$V_{IN}-V_{OUT}\$.

The datasheet also doesn't give the switching frequency range, just one clue in the "Steady State, \$I_{OUT}=0.3A\$" figure on page 7 where the switching frequency is 100 KHz.

How do I determine the fixed \$I_{peak}\$ value based on my \$V_{IN}-V_{OUT}\$ value for this IC?

(I've selected the part based on the high input voltage range and availability from LCSC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *but I don't understand how to determine this fixed Ipeak*

Try this: -

[image]

And this: -

[image]

Comment: I saw the limit value, does it apply for all \$V_{IN}-V_{OUT}\$ combinations? I though it was specific to a voltage difference value, as it says "for a given input voltage and output voltage".

Comment: They don't say that - they say that to calculate L you must use Ipeak and input-output voltage as per Faraday's law of induction. Because the device operates in boundary conduction mode Iout is half Ipeak.